# what to do in case of error MissingReferenceException?

Tags: 2d

MissingReferenceException: The object of type 'GameObject' has been destroyed but you are still trying to access it.
Your script should either check if it is null or you should not destroy the object.
UnityEngine.Object.Internal_InstantiateSingle (UnityEngine.Object data, UnityEngine.Vector3 pos, UnityEngine.Quaternion rot) (at <913bb12059fd4cef8da5cc94ad2f0933>:0)
UnityEngine.Object.Instantiate (UnityEngine.Object original, UnityEngine.Vector3 position, UnityEngine.Quaternion rotation) (at <913bb12059fd4cef8da5cc94ad2f0933>:0)
UnityEngine.Object.Instantiate[T] (T original, UnityEngine.Vector3 position, UnityEngine.Quaternion rotation) (at <913bb12059fd4cef8da5cc94ad2f0933>:0)
Gun.Update () (at Assets/Gun.cs:24)

here is the complete error. This problem starts when I start shooting at the enemy in unity 2d and most likely this error is in the Enemy code, but I will show all three, because in the error itself it refers to the 24th line of the Gun code.

```
public class Gun : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float offset;
    public GameObject bullet;
    public Transform shotPoint;

    private float timeBtwShots;
    public float startBtwShots;

    void Update()
    {
        Vector3 difference = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition) - transform.position;
        float rotZ = Mathf.Atan2(difference.y, difference.x) * Mathf.Rad2Deg;
        transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(0f, 0f, rotZ + offset);

        if(timeBtwShots <= 0)
        {
            if (Input.GetMouseButton(0))
            {
                Instantiate(bullet, shotPoint.position, transform.rotation);
                timeBtwShots = startBtwShots;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            timeBtwShots -= Time.deltaTime;
        }
    }
}
```

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Bullet : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float speed;
    public float lifetime;
    public float distance;
    public int damage;
    public LayerMask whatIsSolid;

    private void Update()
    {
        RaycastHit2D hitInfo = Physics2D.Raycast(transform.position, transform.up, distance, whatIsSolid);
        if(hitInfo.collider != null)
        {
            if (hitInfo.collider.CompareTag("Enemy"))
            {
                hitInfo.collider.GetComponent<Enemy>().TakeDamage(damage);
            }
            Destroy(gameObject);
        }
        transform.Translate(Vector2.up * speed * Time.deltaTime);
    }
}
```

```
public class Enemy : MonoBehaviour
{
    public int health;
    public float speed;
    

    private void Update()
    {
        if (health <= 0)
        {
            Destroy(gameObject);
        }
        transform.Translate(Vector2.left * speed * Time.deltaTime);
    }

    public void TakeDamage(int damage)
    {
         
        health -= damage;
        
    }
}
```

I tried to change the conditional statements and change the code somewhere, but it doesn't change anything.
Thanks in advance for your reply...